# Конструкция *++argv[0] в языке Си

Tags: c, командная-строка, аргументы

Как в этом примере использования указателей работает конструкция `*++argv[0]` во внутреннем цикле?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int c, except = 0, number = 0;

        while(--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
        {
                printf("argv = %s\n", *argv);
                while(c = *++argv[0])
                        switch(c){
                                case 'x':
                                        except = 1;
                                        break;
                                case 'n':
                                        number = 1;
                                        break;
                                default:
                                        printf("Illegal option: %c\n", c);
                                        argc = 0;
                                        break;
                        }

        }

        printf("[DEBUG]: argc = %d\n", argc);

        if(argc != 1)
                printf("Usage: -x -n\n");
        else
                printf("x = %d, n = %d\n", except, number);
        return 0;
}
```

Разберу похожую конструкцию `(*++argv)[0]` во внешнем цикле. Здесь берется нулевой символ строки, которая содержит один из аргументов. Скобки `[]` имеют более высокий приоритет, чем инкремент и ссылка, поэтому `*++argv` заключается в скобки. Нулевой элемент массива `argv` это указатель на имя программы, поэтому инкрементом переходим к следующий строке. После этого разыменовываем указатель и получаем строку. Применение скобок `[0]` дает нулевой символ этой строки.

Конструкция `*++argv[0]` мне совсем непонятна. Здесь должен быть проход по строке-аргументу. Это нужно для того, чтобы поддерживались не только ключи типа `-x -n`, но и ключи вида `-nx`. Для чего здесь `[0]`? Как работает выражение целиком?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну а здесь просто проход посимвольно - как вы написали сами, квадратные скобки имеют более высокий приоритет, так что просто увеличивается указатель `argv[0]`, который изначально указывает на начало строки аргументов, а разыменование дает очередной символ...

Т.е. если вызывается программа так, что `argv[1] == -abcxn`, то после первой строки `(++argv)[0]` указатель `argv[0]` указывает на строку `-abcxn`. Первое разыменование (в первом `while`) дает `'-'`, затем, во втором `while`, просто перебираются все символы строки - `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `n`.

Comment: "увеличивается указатель argv[0], который изначально указывает на начало строки аргументов" Вот это непонятно. Очевидно, что в argv[0] ключи командной строки, а не имя программы. Но почему они в argv[0], а не в argv[1]?

Comment: Потому что перед этим был вызван `(++argv)`, так что произошло смещение по массиву. `--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-'` тут происходит уменьшение `argc` (чтоб не выскочить за границы массива `argv`) и смещение `argv` (т.е. проход *по всем параметрам* командной строки). Ну, и при первом же аргументе командной строки, не начинающемся с `'-'`, происходит выход из цикла.

Comment: `а разыменование дает очередной символ... ` в нашем случае, массив `char`, а не символ, а у массива уже проверяем первый элемент

Comment: Да, теперь ясно. Передается ведь не массив, а указатель на него, а по указателю можно итерировать как угодно.

Comment: А программа с аргументами -x -n почему-то выводит Usage. Странно, нет ведь ошибок в логике.

Comment: Конечно. Потому что у вас usage выводится **в любом случае**, после разбора параметров.